# ASP.NET Local Development Setup

Tags: asp.net, windows

I would like to start learning ASP.NET on a for-fun project. I'm hoping to setup a local server to do my development on, but I don't want to pollute my user account with a webserver, database, and developer tools.

I'm using Vista Home Premium as my desktop OS. Is it possible to setup a separate user in vista and contain all the developer stuff inside it? (Keep sql server, IIS, and Visual Studio separate so they don't run when I'm not doing development work)

If this isn't possible can someone suggest a good alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't see any benefits of creating a separate user for this. There's a webdevserver bundled with VS for development use. This only runs when you start it. And VS itself doesn't do anything unless you are using it...

SQL Server can be set to be started manually.

If you're just getting started, check out the [express editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/default.aspx) of visual web developer and sql server.

Answer (score 10):

Use a virtual machine such as VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ocdecio: a virtual machine is the way to go.  The nice thing, as well, is that you can take a few hours to configure your development environment and then *save* it intact.  That way, if you ever hose it, you do not have to spend another day configuring it. Think of it as "Environment Management" to go along with your Source Code Management. The only caveat is to make sure you have plenty of RAM (2+ GB).  RAM is much cheaper than time these days!

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the above.

I have all the dev stuff on my one user account (I'm using Vista Home Premium too), but nothing runs unless I ask it too.

When installing Sql Server, you should be prompted if you want the service to start automatically or manually. Choose manual and run off one user account.

Answer (score 0):

@mdbritt
This case is a development learning env for asp.net. I can hardly believe that a virtual environment is preferred for this. Nor for any other normal development environment.

Why not just create an image of the hard drive if you want to avoid time spent on reinstall and reconfigure?

Comment: I work in VMWare all day every day on a Mac Pro and it is bulletproof and easy to manage: the "cost" is near zero. Re-imaging a hard drive is simply more work with less payoff - especially since I have multiple VMs specialized for different tasks (e.g. Windows dev under Delphi vs Web dev under VS).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ocdecio: a virtual machine is the way to go. For some things, you can even download fully functional VM's direct from MS (ie Sharepoint Development). The VM's can be a real timesaver and they're easy to backup in entirety.